# Передача в Яндекс Карты адреса

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Появилась необходимость подключить яндекс карты с перечнем пунктов выдачи заказов DPD. У них я получил файл xls с данными о каждом адресе, как теперь их можно подключить к Яндекс Картам?

Сама карта подключена вот так:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var map;
    ymaps.geolocation.get().then(function (res) {
        var mapContainer = $('#map'),
            bounds = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'),

            mapState = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
                bounds,
                [mapContainer.width(), mapContainer.height()]
            );
        createMap(mapState);
    }, function (e) {

        createMap({
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 2
        });
    });

    function createMap (state) {
        map = new ymaps.Map('map', state);
    }
});
```

Comment: преводить адрес в широту и долготу и  `center: [55.751574, 37.573856]`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ center - указывает центр карты, переназначение центра не поможет добавить список адресов на карту. Нужно добавлять метки, а центр не трогать.

Comment: @Reni из вопроса понятно что речь идет о метках, но когда я писал этот коммент я это не смог понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в файле только адреса без координат, то потребуется добавлять их на карту через геокодирование. Для этого в JS API используется метод [`ymaps.geocode()`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode?from=SO). Есть [пример в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode?from=SO).

Вам нужно будет пройтись по файлу с адресами в цикле, каждый прогеокодировать и добавить метку на карту.

Метки добавляются с помощью класса [Placemark](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.xml?from=SO). Например:

```
myMap.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.684758, 37.738521]))
```